# How to Actively handle Azure Service Bus Queue Messages

Tags: azure, nservicebus, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

We are currently leveraging Azure Service Bus to handle various messages from our application.

I want to know what is the best way to handle those messages in real time?

Is there a way to auto perform a script when a message is put into the queue?

Im just thinking that there has to be a better way than having a separate application check the queue every minute/30 seconds/etc.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check the bus based on a timer constantly.

Service Bus topics and subscriptions support a publish/subscribe messaging communication model.

When a message is sent to a topic, it is then made available to each subscription to handle/process independently.

Here is a C# sample on how you can receive a message from a topic:

```
string connectionString =
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");

SubscriptionClient Client =
    SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString
            (connectionString, "TestTopic", "HighMessages");

// Configure the callback options.
OnMessageOptions options = new OnMessageOptions();
options.AutoComplete = false;
options.AutoRenewTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

Client.OnMessage((message) =>
{
    try
    {
        // Process message from subscription.
        Console.WriteLine("\n**High Messages**");
        Console.WriteLine("Body: " + message.GetBody<string>());
        Console.WriteLine("MessageID: " + message.MessageId);
        Console.WriteLine("Message Number: " +
            message.Properties["MessageNumber"]);

        // Remove message from subscription.
        message.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Indicates a problem, unlock message in subscription.
        message.Abandon();
    }
}, options);
```

Here is more details about the publisher subscriber model:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/

Comment: What handles/processes the message? where would this code go that it could handle a message that is sent to a topic instantly? ... I currently have a separate application that is using similar code as above, but it is firing every minute and I'm not sure where/how I would put the code to instantaneously fire when a message is received. Is it a Azure Webjob/etc.?

Comment: This method handles/processes the message: Client.OnMessage((message) =>
{

Comment: @Nefariis About the one minute that is the default value for AutoRenewTimeout property which you can change. AutoComplete is set to false to enable manual control of when to call Complete on the received message. AutoRenewTimeout is set to 1 minute, which causes the client to wait for up to one minute before terminating the auto-renewal feature and the client makes a new call to check for messages.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes down to infrastructure code, I'd rather not write any code. After all, the last thing you want to see is a bug in your infrastructure code that results a data/message loss.

The alternative of using bare-bone Azure Service Bus is to use a library to abstract away all of that code for you. Ultimately you'll declare your messages - your events and commands - and you have handlers that would get fired when there's a message. All the message pumping, queue creation, retries, handling of errors and audits and transactions which are only the tip of the iceberg comes with such frameworks.

As to which framework to use, there's [Nimbus](https://github.com/NimbusAPI/Nimbus) and [NServiceBus](https://particular.net/nservicebus) and possibly others. NServiceBus is a commercial product which comes with [extensive documentation](https://docs.particular.net), [devops](https://docs.particular.net/servicepulse/) and [debugging and visualization](https://docs.particular.net/serviceinsight/) utilities and additional paid support should you need it. Here's how you get an NServiceBus endpoint up and running with Azure ServiceBus:

```
var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("Endpoint1");
endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");

var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>();
var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureServiceBus.ConnectionString");

transport.ConnectionString(connectionString);
transport.UseTopology<ForwardingTopology>();

var endpointInstance = await Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

var message = new Message1
{
    Property = "Hello from Endpoint1"
};

await endpointInstance.Send(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

and on the recipient side, all you need is to have a handler class:

```
public class MyMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<Message1>
{
    public Task Handle(Message2 message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        //Do your task
        Console.WriteLine(message.Property);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

*P.S. I work for Particular Software the makers of NServiceBus but I have used both of the recommended frameworks. You'll need to decide which one is a good fit for you.*